# Cannot convert .pb file into .tflite file

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I am trying to convert my saved_model.pb into .tflite but facing an error. The code I am running is,

```
tflite_convert 
--output_file model.tflite 
--saved_model_dir   trained-inference-graphs/output_inference_graph_v1/saved_model 
--output_format TFLITE 
--inference_type FLOAT 
--input_arrays image_tensor 
--input_shapes 1,300,300,3 
--output_arrays detection_boxes,detection_classes,detection_scores,num_detections
```

and the error I am getting is

```
F tensorflow/lite/toco/tooling_util.cc:2258] Check failed: array.data_type == array.final_data_type Array "image_tensor" has mis-matching actual and final data types (data_type=uint8, final_data_type=float).
Fatal Python error: Aborted
```

I am using tensorflow version 1.14.0.

Comment: I think the `--inference_type FLOAT` should be `--inference_type uint8`. I think you are using a quantize aware training model and trying to convert it to tflite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
tflite_convert
--graph_def_file=tflite_graph.pb #your save model
--output_file=detect.tflite
--input_shapes=1,300,300,3 
--input_arrays=normalized_input_image_tensor
--output_arrays=TFLite_Detection_PostProcess,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2,TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3 
--allow_custom_ops
```

Comment: Thank You very much, mam.

After running your code I got an error, "Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2", which I solved by running this command "conda install tensorflow-mkl".